# 2gb ram, 1.49 usable

Tags: windows-7, memory, gma

See the title. This is a 32 bit system with windows 7. My gfx is gma 950. My question is that does the gma 950 use 512 of shared memory? Also, is there any way to turn this down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/GPU-Z/) utility to get info about your graphics adapter (see 'Sensors' tab -> memory usage). You can usually define amount of memory used by integrated graphics via BIOS settings. If there is no such setting in BIOS, AFAIK there is little you can do about that (you can check driver settings as well, but I've never seen such setting in drivers).